# SSAS Cube deployment error

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube

I was going to process the cube deployment and found the error.

[image]

[image]

I changed the target server name from 'localhost' to this,and tried different way but in vain.

Here is the snap from my SSMS
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have multiple issues going on but the first and foremost is **you do NOT deploy SSAS Multidimensional [MDX] models to a SQL Database Engine Instance**!

Unless you have a very odd configuration ATI-PC\MSSQLSERVER should point to the default MS SQL Server Database Engine Instance NOT an SSAS MDX instance!

The SSMS screen shot you show is for the local host connection you show is for a Database Engine with SQL Server Authentication (SA), which I would assume the instance is called MSSQLSERVER which is the default instance name.

1) What is your SSAS instance name?

2) Does your windows account have permissions? SSAS doesn't allow for SQL server authentication so it must be windows authentication.

3) Is SQL Browser running?

4) Have you configured SQL Browser to allow for the protocols and to allow connections from both Localhost and ATI-PC(InstanceName)?

to connect to Analysis Services Change the Server Type.  When first launching SSMS you can do that via changing server type and then modifying the server name to the appropriate name.

[image]
If your SSMS is already open you can select "Connect" drop down and choose Analysis Services.

[image]

Check on your SQL Browser Configuration by Launching "SQL Server (Version) Configuration Manager" then step through the different areas as far as how to configure it is somewhat self explanatory and because you are deploying an AdeventureWorks cube I would surmise that the configuration would be earlier in you tutorial you are working on.

Comment: No analysis service options in my SSMS, I think thats the first issue :), and I am using SSMS express edition

Comment: BI is not available in SSMS express the cheapest for development will be Developer edition.  You can also do an evaluation for a short time period if you just need a trial https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/sql-server-editions

Comment: Is there any free version to do BI in SSMS for learning and practice purpose ?

Comment: no free version. but free trials. the typical way to do it would be to create a virtual machine and use a trial version of one of the other editions.  It would be good for I believe 30 days. The reason to do it in a VM is so that you can throw away and start the 30 days again if on local machine your registry will show you have already installed a trial version.

Comment: @Zahid if my answer or another worked for you please consider accepting it so others know you got what you needed and reputation points are assigned. thanks http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that you have 'SQL Browser' service running in services.msc. Still I doubt your account which you logged in has access to SSAS and also to connect to that underlying SQL Server. Try checking both for the access, if you selected deploy as service account check that account has access in SSAS. If still you have issues trying checking the eventvwr if you are getting any more errors. If it is development box try recycling SSAS services and try deploying?

Comment: in SSMS the instance shows only DATABASE ENGINE connection. no analysis service option there. Is that a problem?

Comment: permissions is a good question and tip but the number 1 issue is that MSSQLSERVER is the default name for a Database Engine Instance NOT a SSAS MDX instance